# React JS Parsing error: Missing semicolon when importing Firebase Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

`

```
  onSignInSumbit(){
    const phoneNumber = this.state.mobile();
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then((confirmationResult) => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    });
  }
```

`

Don't know what's wrong but getting missing semicolon:
Can any one help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Need more code to help you with this.

In general, you need a `function` keyword in front of the function name unless it's inside of a class. For example you would change your code to:

```js
function onSignInSubmit() {
```

OR

```js
class MyClass {
  onSigninSubmit() {
    //...
  }
}
```